# How to master memory-related coding in OS development?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

It's easy to find a tutorial to setup paging in a minimal OS or how to write an allocator.

I'm interested in learning about call gates, memory fences/barriers and the design of OS memory layout (why's, do's and don'ts). I don't know how to phrase it more concretely but I want to know all the intricancies of memory catering in a OS particularly with regard to multitasking.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read Ulrich Drepper's [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf)? It's a relatively safe place to start for this topic.